# why my mails from zimbra server to yahoo goes in to spam folder

Tags: spam, spamassassin, zimbra, dspam

I just configured zimbra mail server but mail from my zimbra to yahoo, hotmail etc going into there spam folder any suggestion???

bellow is header part from yahoo of that mail

X-DSPAM-Result:  Innocent
X-DSPAM-Class:   Innocent
X-DSPAM-Confidence:  1.00
X-DSPAM-Probability:     0.0023
X-DSPAM-Signature:   N/A
X-Virus-Scanned:     amavisd-new at
X-Spam-Flag:     NO
X-Spam-Score:    -5.399
X-Spam-Level:
X-Spam-Status:   No, score=-5.399 tagged_above=-10 required=6.6 tests=[ALL_TRUSTED=-1.8, BAYES_00=-2.599, DSPAM:Innocent=-1.000] autolearn=ham

Comment: This is an exact duplicate by the same OP.  http://serverfault.com/questions/124253/why-is-my-zimbra-mail-going-into-the-spam-folder-of-yahoo-hotmail-etc/124263#124263

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test). It will tell you what could be wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Configure reverse lookup in your public DNS, some mail servers check for reverse lookups